# "prime faces undefined, Object expected : when accordion panel has data table command buttons and confirm dailogues insides each tab

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Message: 'PrimeFaces' is undefined,
Message: Object expected:

This error appears on IE8 especially when there is Accordion panel.After refreshing the page there is no error.  Accordion panel basically does not work on IE on initial load when accordion panel has data table command buttons and confirm dailogues insides each tab.Can any body have a work around on this.  I am using using prime faces 3.4, jsf2 with myfaces

```
  <p:accordionPanel  value="#{testBean.systems}" var="system"  dynamic="true">  

                  <p:tab title="#{system.name}" id="systemId">  
                 <p:commandButton process="@this"  value="edit" icon="ui-icon-pencil" styleClass="btn-primary" style="margin-left:734px;" action="#{testBean.edit}">

                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{testBean.formBean}" value="#{system}"></f:setPropertyActionListener>

                </p:commandButton>              
                <p:commandButton value="delete" icon="ui-icon-trash"  styleClass="btn-primary" style="width:70px;" oncomplete="confirmDeleteDialog.show()"/>

                <p:confirmDialog message="message" width="200" 
                                 showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode" 
                                 header="Confirm" severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmDeleteDialog"> 

                    <p:commandButton  process="@this" value="#{msg.EditSystem_confirmAnswer1}"  action="#{testBean.deleteSystem}" oncomplete="confirmDeleteDialog.hide()">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{testBean.formBean}" value="#{system}"></f:setPropertyActionListener>
                    </p:commandButton> 
                    <p:commandButton value="#{msg.EditSystem_confirmAnswer2}" onclick="confirmDeleteDialog.hide()" type="button" /> 

                </p:confirmDialog>  



                     <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="tester" value="#{system.studs}" rowKey="#{tester.id}">  

                     <p:column id="serName"  sortBy="#{tester.name}"  headerText="#{msg.AddService_serName}"> 

                         <p:commandLink value="#{tester.name}" immediate="true" process="@this" action="#{testBean1.edit}">  
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener   target="#{testBean1.testId}" value="#{tester.id}"/>
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener   target="#{testBean1.testId2}" value="#{tester.desc}"/>
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener   target="#{testBean1.testId3}" value="#{tester.name}"/>
                         </p:commandLink>

                    </p:column>
```

Comment: I have no problems when using primefaces on IE8. Please post minimal code which can be used to reproduce this problem, and versions of Primefaces and JSF implementation.

Comment: I am using jsf2 and primefaces3.4. I got this error when accordion panel has data table and many command buttons insides each tab of accordion panel

Comment: Edit your question, add this comment, also add facelet code. Write are you using Mojarra or MyFaces implementation.

Comment: Do you have `DOCTYPE` definition on top of page? An you are not manually importing JavaScript files?

Comment: yes partlov: Its like this <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">, I have head tag as well (h:head).

Comment: after migrating to prime faces 3.5 There is no such error now. It works fine